# How can I write a Dataset<Row> into kafka output topic on Spark Structured Streaming - Java8

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to use `ForeachWriter` interface in Spark 2.1 it's  interface, but I cannot use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to know is that, if you working with spark structured Stream and processing streaming data, you'll be having a streaming Dataset.

Being said, the way to write this streaming Dataset is by calling the **ForeachWriter**, you got it right..

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter
  val writer = new ForeachWriter[Commons.UserEvent] {
  override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long) = true
  override def process(value: Commons.UserEvent) = {
  processRow(value)
 }
 override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable) = {}
 }

 val query =
 ds.writeStream.queryName("aggregateStructuredStream").outputMode("complete").foreach(writer).start
```

And the function that writes into topic will be like:

```
    private def processRow(value: Commons.UserEvent) = {
     /*
     *  Producer.send(topic, data)
     */
   }
```

Comment: I'm on Java 8, but thank you dude. I'll try later :)

Comment: The implementation of this code in Java 8 won't be difficult at all. You'll have a `ForeachWriter write = new ForeachWriter(clasz)` . The rest `override def` are `private void` That's pretty all. I'll leave you to it now

Answer (score 1):

It will be supported in Spark 2.2.0. To learn how to use it, I suggest you read this blog post: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html

You can try Spark 2.2.0 RC2 [1] or just wait for the final release.

Another option is taking a look at this blog if you cannot use Spark 2.2.0+:

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/04/real-time-end-to-end-integration-with-apache-kafka-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html

It has a very simple Kafka sink and maybe that's enough for you.

[1] http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/VOTE-Apache-Spark-2-2-0-RC2-td21497.html